# CSS Selector in Selenium - Web Scraping

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am doing Linkedin web **scraping** as a part of my college project. This is the code to locate the skills & endorsements, recommendations and accomplishments section:

```
skills = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#ember661')

recom = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#ember679')

acc = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#ember695')
```

But I am getting an empty list in all the three variables. Please help!

Comment: I tried this out but I am still getting empty lists!

Comment: I guess you mean “scraping” - i.e. getting data by reading it from HTML web pages - rather than “scrapping” - i.e. throwing away.

Comment: @KhushiThakkar see my updated answer

Comment: Don't use those ids, you want to go by the text on the page. Everything else will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of reasons.

1. ID is geneerated and not the same for all the profiles.
2. You should not expect a list of element. There is a single section of each type on profile page so that a single element would be returned.
3. Those sections might get loaded asynchronously so that the page is loaded but the section has not yet been. So that the locators return false. In such case you need to use explicit waiting. **Like**:

```py
waiter = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) 
skills = waiter.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.pv-skill-categories-section')))
recom = waiter.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.pv-recommendations-section')))
acc = waiter.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.pv-accomplishments-section')))
```